# Как правильно работать с Request Object?

Tags: laravel

Получаю на вывод пустые переменные .. Что я делаю не так ?

[Доки](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests)

Версия по Composer ; `"laravel/framework": "5.5.*",`

```
Route::post('login',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

$nick = $request->input('nick_name');
$email = $request->route('email');
$password = $request->route('password');

return view('login',
['nick'=>$nick,'email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]);
});
```

```html
      @if(empty($nick) && empty($password) && empty($email))
          Empty Variables
      @endif
      <form id="login-form" method="post" action="{{url('login')}}">
          {{csrf_field()}}
          <div id="login_block">
              <div class="form-group-sm">
                  <label for="nick_name">Nickname</label>
                  <input id="nick_name" name="nick_name" class="form-control"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group-sm">
                  <label for="email">Email</label>
                  <input id="email" name="email" class="form-control"/>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group-sm">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <input id="password" name="password" class="form-control"/>
              </div>
              <a href="" id="forgot_p"><h4>Forgot password?</h4></a><a href="" id="not-reg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reg-modal"><h4>Not registered?</h4></a>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Login!</button>
          </div>
```

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
return view('login');
});
```

Для запроса на View страницу .. При переходе по URL загружается login page

```
Route::post('login',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
$nick = $request->get('nick_name');
$email = $request->get('email');
$password = $request->get('password');
if($request->has('email')){print_r(true);} // Находит возвращает 1 в HTML страници .. 
return view('login',['nick'=>$nick,'email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Дам совет, сделайте дамп объекта `$request` и увидите все его свойства. Но для решения вашей проблемы используйте динамические свойства объекта `$request`

```
Route::get('login',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){
  return view('login');
});

Route::post('login',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){

  $nick = $request->nick_name; // или $request->get('nick_name');
  $email = $request->email; // или $request->get('email');
  $password = $request->password;  // или $request->get('password');

  return view('login',
    ['nick'=>$nick,'email'=>$email,'password'=>$password]);
});
```

Конечно есть сомнения в правильности использования такого обработчика, но это уже не мое дело))

Comment: Я играюсь с фреймворком .. 
Не понятно почему вариант из доков не работает ????

Comment: У меня не работает не один из ваших примеров .. 
Что не так в моём коде ? Я сейчас кого то убью ..
Всё возвращается пустое ..

Comment: Пустой экран потому, что это обработчик POST запроса.Какой у вас обработчик get запроса?

Comment: Мне не нужен обработчик get Запроса ..

Comment: Пустой экран потому, что это обработчик POST запроса - Что вы имеете ввиду ?

Comment: При запросе в браузере страницы `http://site.app/login` отрабатывает обработчик GET. Но если у вас нет GET обработчика данного роута, то и не будет ничего отображаться.

Comment: ну так я Submit форме делаю на POST!

Comment: как вы делаете submit, если у вас не отображается ничего?

Comment: Что ?????? 
Я вас не понимаю .. Что в моём вопросе не понятного ? Есть форма я делаю Submit на post по урлу login . Просто .. Но не работает Request выборка почему ??? С верху примеры кода .. Вроде всё расписал ..

Comment: понял, в обработчик добавьте `dd($request);`. пришлите скрин вывода

Comment: Вывод чего именно он много че выводит ?

Comment: добавь `dd($request);` после строчки `Route::post('login',function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request){`, отправь форму на этот uri. посмотри параметры [пример скрина](https://yadi.sk/d/s7l6hsEN3SN429)